# TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarURL' of null | Trying to export the help command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been cleaning my index.js file, and decided I wanted to have the help command somewhere a little more practical. Only problem: in the footer I have the bots avatar, but it comes up with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarURL' of null`

```
//code in help.js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var version = process.env.VERSION;

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    execute(message, args){
        const Discord = require('discord.js');

        const helpcommands = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Akasuki Command List')
        .addField('Info Commands', 'userinfo, version, ping, invite, avatar')
        .addField('Moderation Commands', 'kick, ban, clear')
        .addField('Fun Commands', 'samwise, say')
        .setColor(0xFF8AFF)
        .setFooter(`Akasuki ${version}`, client.user.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(helpcommands);
    }
}
```

```
//code in index.js
if (command === 'help') {
    client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
}
```

I'm also wondering if there is a way to export multiple commands at once, or if all have to be done one-by-one?

If anyone can help me with this error I would be very grateful <3 Thank you for checking this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been cleaning my index.js file, and decided I wanted to have the help command somewhere a little more practical. Only problem: in the footer I have the bots avatar, but it comes up with TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarURL' of null

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarURL' of null` is clear. It's saying that you're attempting to access a property of an object that is null.

To debug this error, you can try logging the object in question: `console.log(client.user)`; If `null` comes up, this may be due to not being logged in with your Discord.js client.

Based on your code, it seems that you've not logged in your Discord.js' Client instance. I'd recommend for you to checkout the [login](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) method, which is what you'd want to use to login to Discord. You want to login to Discord first before accessing your Client's user's properties.

Additionally, to view or create your bot applications, [visit your Discord applications](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/).

> I'm also wondering if there is a way to export multiple commands at once, or if all have to be done one-by-one?

A simple way to export multiply commands is by using an array. You could define and export multiple commands like so:

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        // command 1 ...
    },
    {
        // command 2 ...
    ]
];
```

Then you could use a loop to access them.

Comment: `console.log(client.user);` did not work. How can I use the other solution?

Comment: @Miki I've edited my answer to resolve the issue within your code. Please take another look at it.